# Sorting plug-ins type Date doesn't work. Javascript (Angular5+)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, sorting, datatables

My code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#tableEventos').dataTable({
    'columnDefs': [
      { 'targets': [5, 6], 'orderable': true, 'type': 'date-eu' }
    ]
  });

  $('#tableEventos').DataTable();
} );
```

The API response date in String format, like this:

```
{   
//other data...

"dtInicialEvento": "26/09/2018",
"dtFinalEvento": "26/09/2018"

//other data...
```

}

Other configurations work fine, but sorting date still doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

I'm looking up this documentation: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/

**ps: I'm using Angular5+**